# Installing and using Gradle in a docker image/container

Tags: java, gradle, build, docker, dockerfile

I am getting this strange error at the end of the process of creating a docker image from a `Dockerfile`:

```
/bin/sh: 1: gradle: not found
INFO[0003] The command [/bin/sh -c gradle test jar] returned a non-zero code: 127
```

The relevant part of the `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM debian:jessie
[...]
RUN curl -L https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.4-bin.zip -o gradle-2.4-bin.zip
RUN apt-get install -y unzip
RUN unzip gradle-2.4-bin.zip
RUN echo 'export GRADLE_HOME=/app/gradle-2.4' >> $HOME/.bashrc
RUN echo 'export PATH=$PATH:$GRADLE_HOME/bin' >> $HOME/.bashrc
RUN /bin/bash -c "source $HOME/.bashrc"
RUN gradle test jar
[...]
```

The command I am using is: `docker build -t java_i .`

The strange thing is that if:

- I run a container from the previous image commenting out `RUN gradle test jar` (command: `docker run -d -p 9093:8080 -p 9094:8081 --name java_c -i -t java_i`),
- then I log into that container (command: `docker exec -it java_c bash`),
- then I manually check the gradle environment variables finding them,
- then I manually run that commented out command from within the running container (`gradle test jar`):

I eventually get the expected output (the compiled java code in the `build` folder).

I am using Docker version 1.6.2

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I solved the problem using the `ENV` docker instructions ([link to the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#env)).

```
ENV GRADLE_HOME=/app/gradle-2.4
ENV PATH=$PATH:$GRADLE_HOME/bin
```

Comment: Can you post the dockerfile after changes?

Comment: Just replace `RUN echo 'export GRADLE_HOME=/app/gradle-2.4' >> $HOME/.bashrc
RUN echo 'export PATH=$PATH:$GRADLE_HOME/bin' >> $HOME/.bashrc
RUN /bin/bash -c "source $HOME/.bashrc"` with `ENV GRADLE_HOME=/app/gradle-2.4
ENV PATH=$PATH:$GRADLE_HOME/bin`

Answer (score 5):

This command `/bin/bash -c "source $HOME/.bashrc"` means that you create a new non-interactive process and run a command in it to set environment variables there. Which does not affect the parent process. As soon as variables are set, process exits. You can check this by running something like this:

```
RUN /bin/bash -c "source $HOME/.bashrc; env"
RUN env
```

What should be working is this option:

```
RUN source ~/.bashrc
```

And the reason why it works when you log in, is because the new process reads already updated `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: Thank you for the hint! But I was already trying that kind of thing (I forgot to mention sorry) and the problem I think is that `source` is not a normal command but a shell builtin, the error I get: `/bin/sh: 1: source: not found
INFO[0002] The command [/bin/sh -c source ~/.bashrc] returned a non-zero code: 127`

Answer (score 3):

I was trying to install same version with `JDK 11.0.7` but `gradle-2.4` does not work. and got below error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine java version from '11.0.7'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

I install later version to fix the above issue after installation.
Posting as an answer might help someone else.

```
FROM openjdk:11.0.7-jdk
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y unzip
WORKDIR /gradle
RUN curl -L https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5.1-bin.zip -o gradle-6.5.1-bin.zip
RUN unzip gradle-6.5.1-bin.zip
ENV GRADLE_HOME=/gradle/gradle-6.5.1
ENV PATH=$PATH:$GRADLE_HOME/bin
RUN gradle --version
```

Comment: Yes indeed, the answer helps people to install a newer version than gradle-2.4 when using Java 11. 

Answer (score 2):

You can use multi-stage builds and the Gradle Docker image (no need to install Gradle...) to build the application then use the result in the runtime container:

```
# Build
FROM gradle AS build

WORKDIR /appbuild
COPY . /appbuild

RUN gradle --version
# here goes your build code
```

Once the Gradle build is done, switch to the runtime container:

```
# Runtime
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine

# more stuff here...

COPY --from=0 appbuild/<somepath>/some.jar application.jar

# more stuff here...
```

The COPY command copies the build artifacts from the build phase to the runtime container (in this case a jar file).